Place checkboxes in positions relative to image Jetpack Compose
I am learning Kotlin for the first time and developing an app using Jetpack Compose to log bones on an archaeological site. This app will be used on different devices with different screen sizes. The bones are logged by opening an image of a bone and clicking on checkboxes on the image to mark particular fragments of the bone that have been found. To do this, the checkboxes have to be placed exactly where the fragment is on the bone. Unfortunately, the positions of the checkboxes change whenever I test with a different device size on the emulator. How can I place the checkboxes relative to the image so they appear in the exact same coordinates on the image, no matter what the size of the screen/image is?
I am able to extract the relative positioning of where these checkboxes should go on the image by logging click events on it but can't seem to convert these into x and y values for Modifier.offset(). E.g., these are where the three checkboxes should go:
2024-09-23 10:38:32.021  5058-5058  Image click com.example.logger D  x: 0.5133263, y: 0.37671298
2024-09-23 10:38:33.768  5058-5058  Image click com.example.logger D  x: 0.21499948, y: 0.45003778
2024-09-23 10:38:36.898  5058-5058  Image click com.example.logger D  x: 0.8219602, y: 0.45003778

Below is a template I have of where this code must work. I pass in a list of checked states and changes for the checkboxes (as their number varies across bones), as well as a list of coordinates for where to place each checkbox (in a variable coordinates)
BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            val imageWidth = maxWidth
            val imageHeight = maxHeight

            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.hyd),
                    contentDescription = "Image of hyoid",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.9f)
                )

                checkedStates.forEachIndexed { index, checked ->
                        // position a checkbox 
                        Checkbox(
                            checked = checked,
                            onCheckedChange = changes[index],
                            modifier = Modifier.offset(x = ?, y = ?)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }


Are these coordinates, x: 0.5133263, y: 0.37671298, correspond to percentage of Bitmap in a range of 0f..1f?

It was the relative position but I have changed it to absolute values on the bitmap, e.g., my first coordinate is now stored in Pair(592, 136). I have calculated the positions as such:
val positionX = 592 * (bitmapDpSize.width / imageSize.width) val positionY = 136 * (bitmapDpSize.height / imageSize.height)
But my checkboxes are all over the place!

If you set Alignment.Center that offset are applied from center of the Box not from top left. Second thing is if you wish to make Composable smaller you should do it with parent you get 100% of parent dimensions via imageWidth and height but your Image covers 90% of parent. That's also not correct. Other than that this is very simple ratio. If you have a 100x100 plane and if you scale it by 2 for instance, it becomes 200x200. And if you wish to find center in second plane which is (100, 100) all you do is center in origian plane * ratio between planes.

@Thracian I see, I have set alignment to TopStart but I think the issue is the image is not completing filling the Image composable which I'm taking the size from. I'm having a look at the code you linked with the formula to calculate the area in the Image that the bitmap covers but I'm a bit confused about where all the inputs are coming from here private fun getDrawAreaRect(     dstSize: Size,     scaledSrcSize: Size,     horizontalBias: Float,     verticalBias: Float ) . By the way, thankyou for your help so far!

src size in Jetpack Compose refers to Bitmap size, dstSize is Composable size. scaledSrcSize is after getting scale factors for ContentScale and alignment biases depend on Image's alignment property. I will post a basic sample and i can post an answer that explains each step for more complex one like in the link when i have more time

Updated answer with sample with checkBoxes. I will explain step by step how it works in more complex scenarios with a new answer and explaining logic behind each step when i have more time, probably weekend i hope.

@Thracian thankyou so much, you’re a legend! I will work through the code you’ve provided with my image and see how it goes.

You can calculate x and coordinates on screen as
position on Screen = positionX on Bitmap * (Composable width/ Bitmap width)

get bitmap dimensions in dp then you can do it as
modifier = Modifier.offset(x = imageWidth fractionX, y = imageHeightfractionY)
Also you need to set alignment of Box to TopStart since coordinated don't start from center, they start top left of a Bitmap or any plane in general.
val density = LocalDensity.current
val bitmapDpSize: DpSize = with(density) {
    painter.intrinsicSize.toDpSize()
}

Assuming you have coordinates in bitmap, for instance 1000x1000px, such as (400, 400), (500, 700) or (1000,1000) coordinates. You calculate this on Image composable on screen, let's say with 500x500px as
positionX on screen = 400 * 500(Image Composable width) / 1000(Bitmap width)

which returns (200, 200) on Image for a position for (400, 400) on Bitmap.
To explain this as simple as possible i found a 500x500 px landscape picture

And on a Image with 1000x1000 px i will display check boxes on (200, 200) and (250, 250) on Bitmap which should translate to (400, 400) and (500, 500) on Image or screen. Using Modifier.layout lets you get current checkBox size as well and you can offset is half of its dimensions to center.
Result

@Preview
@Composable
fun CheckBoxOnImageSample() {
    val positionList = remember {
        listOf(
            Offset(200f, 200f),
            Offset(250f, 250f),
        )
    }

    val painter = painterResource(R.drawable.landscape500)

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    val widthDp: Dp = with(density) {
        1000f.toDp()
    }

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.size(widthDp)
    ) {
        val imageWidth: Int = constraints.maxWidth
        val imageHeight: Int = constraints.maxHeight

        val bitmapWidth = painter.intrinsicSize.width
        val bitmapHeight = painter.intrinsicSize.height

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().border(2.dp, Color.Red).drawWithContent {
                drawContent()
                drawLine(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    start = Offset(center.x, 0f),
                    end = Offset(center.x, size.height)
                )

                drawLine(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    start = Offset(0f, center.y),
                    end = Offset(size.width, center.y)
                )
            },
            painter = painter,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            alpha = .7f,
            contentDescription = null
        )

        positionList.forEach { offset: Offset ->
            var checked by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }
            Checkbox(
                modifier = Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

                    val posOnScreenX = offset.x * imageWidth / bitmapWidth
                    val posOnScreenY = offset.y * imageHeight / bitmapHeight

                    println("posOnScreenX: $posOnScreenX, posOnScreenY: $posOnScreenY")

                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(
                            (posOnScreenX - placeable.width / 2).toInt(),
                            (posOnScreenY - placeable.height / 2).toInt()
                        )
                    }
                },
                checked = checked,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    checked = it
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

This is the most basic calculation when there are no gaps and all of Bitmap is drawn. When you need to use other ContentScale or Alignments you need to find rectangle of draw area and rectangle of bitmap that is to be drawn as well as in samples below
https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter5_gesture/Tutorial5_15_1ImageBoundsRect.kt

The problem is I need to hardcode the coordinates into the app. The checkboxes are not being generated by users clicking the image, they need to already be displayed when they open the image. Is it possible without getting the user to click somewhere first?

No, you don't need user to click anywhere. You get coordinates from bitmap and scale them to Image on screen. But you need to change contentAlignment = Alignment.Center to TopStart since coordinates on bitmap start from (0, 0)

If a bitmap has 1000x1000 size and it's displayed on screen with Image composable with 500x500px and you wish to display a position in center of Bitmap you just scale it to Image position with the equation above. My example in the link covers touches as well but in this answer i never mentioned about any touch coordinates.

Let's say you have hard coded (400,400) for Bitmap with 1000x1000px size that you display on Image composable with 500x500 pixel. All you have to do is 400 * 500(Image composable width)/1000(bitmap width) and apply same for y as well. This is how you do it in pixels. Since in question you asked with dp, i converted bitmap size to DpSize for convenience.

And if you check this link, you can see hard coded markers are on every image without user clicking anywhere. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter5_gesture/Tutorial5_15ImageBoundsRect.kt Same as the answer in the link. Markers are drawn on any image with any content size or Aligment from hard coded values, then you can add more markers by translating screen position to bitmap position when user touches on screen.

Update: I've implemented the code from above and it is working perfectly! The only issue is some of the images are more wide than they are tall and are getting squashed, is there a way around this? But the checkboxes are placing exactly where they should be between different screen sizes which is perfect.

It depends on aspect ratio of the Image composable. You should either set no height for Iamge composale so it can measure height based on intrinsic value of painter or use ContentScale.Fit or another one for instance. If you wish to use another ContentScale you should implement the one in the link which returns rectangle of draw area of Image.

I will post a general answer why you need all this, but it might take a bit. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/95f3cc8380cddecff696b96991e9887a8f00bc84/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter5_gesture/Tutorial5_15_1ImageBoundsRect.kt#L244 but you can change this answer with your own list and remove touch
